# Check if virtualenv already installed in directory

Tags: python, virtualenv

I want to create a python virtual environment during the build as one of the automated build stages.

In theory I should call `python -m venv ./dir`, but If I already created it I get an error:

`Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.../dir/bin/activate'`

Does anyone know if it is possible to check if the folder already has python virtualenv configured inside it, which doesn't return an error?

Is there some command like `python -m virtualenv -check ./dir`?

Comment: Try using bash command substitution to check the output of the command (assuming you're using a bash script)

Comment: There is no read-made command but you can check existence of `./dir/bin/activate` as a reasonable heuristics.